# How to setup bootstrap-datepicker-rails?

Tags: datepicker, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-ui-datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Anybody knows how to setup the gem bootstrap-datepicker-rails? I followed the steps in http://rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails/0.6.21/frames, basically:

1. I setup `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem
2. I add this to gemfile `gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '>= 0.6.21'`
3. Add this line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

   ```
   *= require bootstrap-datepicker
   ```
4. Add this line to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

   ```
   //= require bootstrap-datepicker
   ```
5. Add this line to app/assets/javascripts/controllername.js.coffee

   ```
   $('.datepicker').datepicker()
   ```
6. Finally use in view :)

   ```
   <input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >
   ```

But it doesn't work!! Anybody has got it to work? It should work nice as shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Gg5k/43/

Comment: i have the same problem, have you found a solution? I keep getting an uncaught exemption that datepicker is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

Look at step 5 and step 6, your selection class `.datepicker` in javascript but not in `input field`

Try this

on views (e.g form)

```
<%= f.text_field :mydate, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
</script>
```

Or As component :

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <%= f.text_field :mydate, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', :disabled => 'disable' %><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Example above all if the attribute using `date` type. 
You can use [bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails) gem, if the attribute using `datetime` type

Comment: how about for rails text field tag which is like   <%= text_field_tag "test", nil, :tabindex => '3', data: { behavior: "datepicker" }, :value =>Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :id => "datepicker" %>

Answer (score 1):

```
In the view, try this:
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Trade Date: ' %>
  <%= f.text_field :trade_date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %><br />
</div>  
In your application.js, use:
$(document).on("focus", "[data-behaviour~='datepicker']", function(e){
    $(this).datepicker({"format": "yyyy-mm-dd", "weekStart": 1, "autoclose": true})
});
instead of 
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same, but I change the code:

> $('.datapicker').datapicker()

By this code:

> $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker()

I try using a class 'datapicker' but not found.

This is my example, I use to HAML and coffeescript

events.js.coffe

> $ ->
>
> $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker()

_form.haml

> = simple_form_for @event, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal well"} do |f|
>
> .field (That is the same )
>
> ```
> = f.input :date, :input_html => { "data-behaviour" => "datepicker" }
> ```
>
> .form-actions
>
> ```
> = f.button :submit, 'Create Event' ,:class => 'btn btn-success btn-large'
> ```