# bootstrap-datepicker-rails not working via simple_form with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to get a datepicker (using [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)) to display via [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), but having no luck.

I've read a bunch of stuff such as:

https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails/issues/51
[How to setup bootstrap-datepicker-rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928918/how-to-setup-bootstrap-datepicker-rails)
http://learningnewtricks.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/bootstrap-date-picker-on-rails-so-simple/
http://www.chadcf.com/blog/jqueryui-datepicker-rails-and-simpleform-easy-way

All I get is a textfield but when I click on it there is no datepicker. Could it be the datepicker is behind the modal, if so how to fix that?

My setup is as follows:

```
fyousuf$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.12

fyousuf$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
    *= require_self
    *= require fullcalendar
    *= require bootstrap-datepicker
    *= require_tree .
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require twitter/bootstrap
    //= require bootstrap
    //= require fullcalendar
    //= require bootstrap-datepicker
    //= require_tree .
```

**app/assets/javascript/s/events.js**

```
    # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
    # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
    # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

    $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({"format": "yyyy-mm-dd", "weekStart": 1,      "autoclose": true});
```

**app/views/events/_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
        ...
        <%= f.input :starts_at, :as => :string, :input_html => { data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}} %>
        ...
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Wrap the `datepicker` initialization code in `events.js` within jquery document ready, i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){/* Your datepicker initialization code here */});`

Comment: Changed to this but still same behavior:

$(document).ready(function()
{
$('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({"format": "yyyy-mm-dd", "weekStart": 1, "autoclose": true});
});

Answer (score 3):

### On my view

```
= f.input :first_name
= f.input :last_name
= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" }
```

### On my application.js

```
$(function() {
    $('input.datepicker').data({behaviour: "datepicker"}).datepicker();
});
```

### The versions that I'm using

```
> bundle | grep bootstrap

Using bootstrap-datepicker-rails 1.3.0.2
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.8
```

It's perfectly working for me. Right after the form is loaded if I click on the input "date_of_birth" the datepicker appears.