# If I use bootstrap-datepicker-rails, should I change the datetime type to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I will use date picker in rails application. My attribute type are `date` and `datetime`.

If I use bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem, should I change them to string?

If not, how to use the datepicker in simple-form?

The answer in [StackOverview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928918/how-to-setup-bootstrap-datepicker-rails) says that `If your attribute using datetime type, you can use bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails gem`, how to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails model attributes can be `datetime` and `date`. Just make the form input fields `text`, not `date` or `datetime`.

Comment: thanks for you answer, do you know how to use it in `simple-form`?

Comment: I haven't used it with `simple-form` though. It should be something like: `f.input :my_date_field, as: :text`